# Receiving following error int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

When I am trying to run the following code from

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-config-rules/blob/master/python/iam-inactive-user.py

I am receiving below-mentioned error. Tried to

```
    {
  "stackTrace": [
    [
      "/var/task/lambda_function.py",
      40,
      "lambda_handler",
      "invoking_event = json.loads(event[\"invokingEvent\"])"
    ]
  ],
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "errorMessage": "'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'"
}
```

Comment: Are you runing that code with Python 2 or 3?

Comment: This needs to invoked by aws config, if you are testing then you need to provide the `AWS config events` in the parameters, here is an example. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/evaluate-config_develop-rules_example-events.html

Comment: Thank you. I will test the same

Comment: Hi  Sudharsan. Thank you for the suggestion. Could you please tell me how to provide the config events